JWT not being sent with request
In my website, after logging in, the server sends a jwt as a response, which is saved in the client side. In devtools, I can see that there's indeed a token in my browser's localstorage.
But when I try to verify the token using this api (post):
exports.verifyToken = async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'No token provided' });
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        console.log("Decoded token:", decoded);
        return res.status(200).send('User is authorized');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Token verification error:', error);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User is unauthorized' });
    }
};

And these are CORS settings in my server.js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: ['Authorization', 'Content-Type'],
}));

Then if I make a request from my client side like this:
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
if (!token) throw new Error("No token found");
console.log("Verifying token:", token);
await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/verifyToken', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
});

Then the response from server is "No token provided" even when there's a token in my localstorage, and there's no Authorization header in the request headers as well. Obviously it logs "undefined" in the server shell.
This is Request Payload in Network tab:
Authorization
: 
"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im5pdGluX2lzX21lIiwibmFtZSI6Ik5pdGluIiwiaWF0IjoxNzI4NTU1MDEzLCJleHAiOjE3Mjg1NjIyMTN9.712RCcZC4v-qLAilVCsRNA7v_xk0vzPwTiXEBQtJUnE"

and the response is:
{"message":"No token provided"}

Logging req.headers logs this:
{
  host: 'localhost:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '220',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/129.0.0.0',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
{
  host: 'localhost:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '220',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/129.0.0.0',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

So, what's really the issue here?
Solved
The error was in axios.post request, instead of:
await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/verifyToken', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
});

It should've been:
await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/verifyToken', {}, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
});

it caused error because, it was sending token in body before, so typing an empty space and sending token in third line solved it!

"and there's no Authorization header in the request headers as well", "This is Request Payload in Network tab: Authorization: Bearer ..." - now which one is it?

@C3roe When i log req.headers in the backend, there's no authorization header there, but in network tools, when i navigate to Payload, then Authorization: Bearer is present in the response, ik this is confusing, but it is what it is

Okay, it wasn't clear that you were talking about logging on the backend side. Then you'll have to figure out, where exactly it gets "lost". I'd start by logging req.headers in full, and see what that contains.

@C3roe yeah, I added the req.headers in the question, thanks

Looks like that header must have been filtered out somewhere along the way. But I couldn't tell you where and why that might have happened.

@C3roe I figured it out lol, check the bottom of my question

Please delete the solution from the question, and add a self-answer. It is preferred that answer material goes in answers here. Thanks!
